# ExpandableListView disappeared form Palette in Android Studio 4.1.1?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

ExpandableListView option is not available in the Palette. Android Studio allows to manually code ExpandableListView in the .XML file. Are they planning of removing that feature completely?

[SCREEN SHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KADTU.png)

Comment: Google does not make many announcements of plans for future versions of Android. Note that `RecyclerView` handles most of the scenarios supported by the old `AdapterView` family, including `ExpandableListView`.